# Gluon android packaging fails on release/signing

Tags: android, release, signing, gluon-mobile

I am following the gluonhq documentation for a release config for android: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_distribution_build and https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_signing_for_release.

I generate a keystore as follows:
`keytool -genkeypair -keyalg rsa -alias pstar -keystore [fullpathtoKS]/PStar.ks -validity 9125 -v`

where [fullpathtoKS] is my path to the keystore.  I enter the prompted info and get the following returned:

```
Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 9,125 days
    for: CN=...
[Storing [fullpathtoKS]/PStar.ks]
```

Then I enter up the required 4 parameters properties on the POM for release:

```
<android-keystore-path>[fullpathtoKS]/PStar.ks</android-keystore-path>
<android-keystore-password>myKSpwd</android-keystore-password>
<android-key-alias>pstar</android-key-alias>
<android-key-password>myKSpwd</android-key-password>
```

On running gluonfx:build and then gluonfx:package, I get the error:

```
[Thu Sept 29 11:39:59 EEST 2022][SEVERE] The key store path [fullpathtoKS]/PStar.ks is not valid. Using Debug signing configuration
Check the log files...
```

But no further info can be found in the logs as to why the packaging fails.
I created a little Java program:

```
String keystore = "[fullpathtoKS]/PStar.ks";
String alias = "pstar";
String aliasPw = "myKSpwd";
String ksPw = "myKSpwd";
        
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

try( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystore) ) {
     ks.load(fis, ksPw.toCharArray());
}

ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(aliasPw.toCharArray()));
```

and no exceptions are thrown.  The paths and passwords are all OK.

So I assume gluon is not happy with the keystore entry itself.  How do I find out what gluonfx:package is complaining about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see comes from [Substrate](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/target/AndroidTargetConfiguration.java#L472), when it tries to evaluate the signing configuration you have provided via the GluonFX plugin:

```
if (keyStorePath == null || 
    ANDROID_KEYSTORE_EXTENSIONS.stream().noneMatch(keyStorePath::endsWith) || 
    !Files.exists(Path.of(keyStorePath)) || keyAlias == null || keyStorePass == null || keyPass == null) {
            if (keyStorePath != null) {
                Logger.logSevere("The key store path " + keyStorePath +
                        " is not valid. Using Debug signing configuration");
            }
            return "Debug";
        }
```

If you check the values in `ANDROID_KEYSTORE_EXTENSIONS`, you'll [see](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/target/AndroidTargetConfiguration.java#L69):

```
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_EXTENSIONS = List.of(".keystore", ".jks");
```

Which, according to the Android documentation, for [app-signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#certificates-keystores):

> Java Keystores (.jks or .keystore) are binary files that serve as repositories of certificates and private keys

are the two valid extensions expected.

This explains why your extension `.ks` is not working.

So all you need to do is rename your key store to `PStar.jks`, or if that doesn't work, generate one again.

Comment: Thank you.  This info should be put into the Gluon sign/release documentation.